# Conditionally create a column equal to a value from a cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data frame

```
data = {'id':['1', '1', '1','1', '2', '2', '2', '2'],'time':['10am', '11am', '12pm', '13pm','10am', '11am', '12pm', '13pm'], 
        'value':[20,21,19,18,56,47,78,96]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to create a column, where the values for each group are equal to the value from column 'value' when column 'time' is 11am.

Here is the example of the desired final dataframe.

```
data2 = {'id':['1', '1', '1','1', '2', '2', '2', '2'],'time':['10am', '11am', '12pm', '13pm','10am', '11am', '12pm', '13pm'], 
        'value':[20,21,19,18,56,47,78,96],'newcolum':['21', '21', '21','21', '47', '47', '47', '47'],}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help

**EDIT**

What should I do if I have 11:00:00 instead of 11am in column time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
```

Try:

```
df=df.set_index('id')
df['newcol']=df['value'].where(df['time'].eq(datetime.time(11,0))).groupby(df.index).transform('first')
df=df.reset_index()
```

**OR**

```
df['newcol']=df['id'].map(df.pivot_table('value','id','time')[datetime.time(11,0)])
```

Comment: Sorry, i have tried your solution, but run into a problem. What should I do if 'time' is not 11am, but 11:00:00. I tried to run with 11:00:00 but all i got is NaN

Comment: @BogdanTitomir then write `11:00:00` instead of `11am` in the condition

Comment: I did, but it returned NaNs

Comment: @BogdanTitomir updated answer....Kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: Another question, what if I also add a day column, now every id have also different day. Now i need to group by also day, where i can add day. If i do `df['newcol']=df.groupby('id', 'day')['value'].transform(lambda x:x.where(df['time'].eq(datetime.time(11,0)))).ffill().bfill()` it says No axis named day for object type DataFrame

Comment: @BogdanTitomir that was because if you are grouping with 2 or more columns then pass the list inside `groupby()` method i.e `['id', 'day']` so it become `df.groupby(['id', 'day'])`

Comment: @BogdanTitomir also use first method in my answer bcz 3rd method is comparitively slow for large datasets ...first one method in my answer will be faster speedwise and performance wise  so in your case do `df=df.set_index(['id', 'day'])` then follow along with steps

Comment: thanks, definitely 3rd method took more than 20 mins, i had to cancel it. The first method works very well, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`groupby(id)` + `transform` that returns the right element does what you want:

```
>>> df = df.set_index(['id', 'time'])
>>> val_at_11am = df.groupby('id').transform(lambda s: s.droplevel(0)['11am'])
>>> val_at_11am
         value
id time       
1  10am     21
   11am     21
   12pm     21
   13pm     21
2  10am     47
   11am     47
   12pm     47
   13pm     47
>>> df['value'] = val_at_11am
>>> df.reset_index()
  id  time  value
0  1  10am     21
1  1  11am     21
2  1  12pm     21
3  1  13pm     21
4  2  10am     47
5  2  11am     47
6  2  12pm     47
7  2  13pm     47
```

Note that we had to tweak it a little here to pass in the `time` (as index) in order to select the `11am` values.

An alternate way without modifying the index, is to fetch the corresponding from within the transform, filter the ones that are 11am, and return the first value:

```
>>> df.groupby('id')['value'].transform(lambda s: s.loc[df.loc[s.index, 'time'] == '11am'].iloc[0])
0    21
1    21
2    21
3    21
4    47
5    47
6    47
7    47
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution also works very well

Comment: Thanks, it appears that your solution works faster. Could you clarify, what should i do if i have 11:00:00 instead of 11am

Comment: @BogdanTitomir It depends, if it’s a still string then replace `== '11am'` with `== '11:00:00'`, if it’s a datetime then maybe use `.dt.hour == 11`